# Selective text extraction in Python based on certain topics or keywords

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim, pythonanywhere

I have a quite long text document describing behaviours of different animals. I want to extract text about a specific animal and haven't figured out how this can be done.

So for example, if the document descibes 15 different animals, I want my alorithm to output all information from the input file that related to lions. Lions described and discussed in several different places of the document - how do I do "selective extraction" for text that is only related to lions, does anyone know?

## EDIT - inputs and outputs

Inputs:
(1) Text file (e.g. "document.txt")
(2) Key word(s) (e.g. "lion")

Output (example):
"Lions are large felines that are traditionally depicted as the 'king of the jungle.' These big cats once roamed Africa, Asia and Europe. [...] Males are generally larger than females and have a distinctive mane of hair around their heads [...] Asiatic lions eat large animals as well, such as goats, nilgai, chital, sambhar and buffaloes. [...] Females have a gestation period of around four months. She will give birth to her young away from others and hide the cubs for the first six weeks of their lives."

Comment: Input and output example please!

Comment: Any reproducible code for us to debug?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your document expresses some natural structure in the text like paragraphs – perhaps with newlines after each paragraph, or blank lines between paragraphs.

So a simple baseline would be: return every paragraph that contains the word `'lion'`.

If the text already has one paragraph per line, this could be as simple as using the command-line `egrep` utility, as for example here to find 'lion' or 'lions' bracketed by word-boundaries:

```
egrep "\wlions?\w" document.txt
```

If that's insufficient, you should expand your question with more precise examples of the ways you'd like to do better than that simple baseline.

For example, if it's important to return text segments smaller than a paragraph:

- can you provide examples of your input documents where this is important, and exactly which segments of a paragraph should/should-not bet selected? (Your current example only shows what you want, and not the kind of non-relevant text you'd like the approach to reject.)
- would the similarly-simple approach of just every **sentence** with `'lion'` in it work better for your purposes? Or, every such sentence plus the sentence before and after? (Or, if you wanted to get really fancy, you could look into libraries for "anaphora resolution" – determining what nearby subjects, in the same or other sentences, words like `'she'` or `'they'` or `'it'` refer to – and then expand the core set of obvious sentences with any other nearby sentences using such pronouns.)
- if some of your "tough cases" for the simple-strategy involve understanding synonyms for query words – for example, your query is `'dog'` but you want to catch sentences about `'canines'` or `'mutts'` or individual breeds – then maybe you need to expand the query-word with synonyms or hyponyms (words for more-specific variants), using either pre-built lexicons (like WordNet) or fuzzier word-similarities that could be learned from your domain text (like word2vec word-vectors).

But, you'd need to show more of your example input (source documents in detail, with good and bad text ranges, and more example queries), desirable output, and challenging cases where a simple keyword-grep doesn't work.